# Matching two ArrayList value in android

Tags: android, arraylist

I have two `ArrayList`. First contains class name such as Ab,BB,CC and second `ArrayList` contains class name and name. I want that when I select the class name from first `ArrayList`, then show only name which name is match first `ArrayList` name. How is it possible?

Here are some code snippets:

```
JSONArray array3 = object.getJSONArray("class");
for(int x = 0; x<array3.length(); x++){
    JSONObject object1=array3.getJSONObject(x);
    c = object1.getString("class");
    classItem.add(c);
}
```

---

```
JSONArray array4 = object.getJSONArray("subclass");
for(int z = 0; z<array4.length(); z++){
    JSONObject object1 = array4.getJSONObject(z);
    String name = object1.getString("Name");
    String cname = object1.getString("class");
    subclassitm.add(name);
}
```

`array3` contains only class name and `array4` contains name and class name. I want when I select class from `array3` then only show name in `array4`.

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: JSONArray array3 = object.getJSONArray("class");
                for(int x= 0;x<array3.length();x++){
                    JSONObject object1=array3.getJSONObject(x);
                    c = object1.getString("class");
                    classItem.add(c);
                }

Comment: JSONArray array4 = object.getJSONArray("subclass");
                for(int z =0;z<array4.length();z++){
                    JSONObject object1 = array4.getJSONObject(z);
                    String name = object1.getString("Name");
                    String cname = object1.getString("class");
                    subclassitm.add(name);
                }

Comment: array3 contain only class name and array4 is contain name and class name.i want when i select class to array3 then only show  name in array4.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
public static String NameFromClassName(Context con,String name) {
    ArrayList<Object> arrLst;//here your first class arraylist

    String mNewname = null;
    for (Object arr : arrLst) {
        if (arr.getClassName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            mNewname = arr.getnameValue().toString();//means match with your selected name and arraylist item
        }
    }
    return mNewname;
}
```